# Why are Virtual Machines used in Ethereum?

Tags: script, ethereum, ethereum-vm

I'm wondering why the Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM) is used?

What if they didn't use it?

Why don't we have them in Bitcoin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*note:* I might be wrong

1. The EVM is actually the core of Ethereum. All contracts are written in EVM bytecode. This doesn't mean that Ethereum includes an actual virtual machine in the sense of Hyper-V, Vmware or Xen. It contains *something[*]* that can execute EVM bytecode (that *something* can either be [interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)), [jit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) or [aot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahead-of-time_compilation)). So, VM in this case is just a name for emulating the bytecode.
2. Without the EVM, all transaction types would have to be hardcoded (this would limit capabilities, but would also be much safer).
3. Why do you think that Bitcoin does not have a VM? It actually has. Script is Bitcoin's bytecode, you can read more about technical details here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.Stackexchange, GiM. Nice debut. ;) I've taken the liberty to switch around a few words in your answer, please take a look if you're happy with my edit and feel free to further amend it to your liking.